# Oracle Agile PLM - Update DB password

Tags: oracle, oracle-agile-plm

Apart from the agile.properties file, where else do I have to update the DB password string for Agile?  Still getting ORA-01017.

I did a grep, the other files that have the string are install\bin\tokens.txt and uninstaller\installvariables.properties, but don't think they matter unless I'm gonna uninstall!

Answer (score 0):

In weblogic you need to change the password for the JDBC | DataSource